# Gsettings and dconf

Tags: 12.10, dconf, gsettings

Hello 
 I need to set a hotkey in ubuntu 12.10, I use:

```
gsettings(dconf)  
 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding '<Primary><Alt>s'<br>  
 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding '<Primary><Alt>s'<br> 
 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ command 'gnome-terminal'
```

But when I look at this schema with gsettings I just see:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
@as []
```

But when I use dconf  to see this schema:

```
dconf list /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/
 binding
 command
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask why you are using `dconf` and `gsettings`?  There are many easier ways to create keyboard shortcuts/hotkeys.

Comment: Because i need to set hot key in post install script. What are this ways?

Comment: Ah, well they won't work for a post install script I'm afraid.

Comment: Why not? 
in ubuntu 12.04 i use gconftool-2 but in 12.10 it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands:

```
dconf read /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/name
dconf read /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/binding
dconf read /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/command
```

Answer (score 1):

First try creating `custom2`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['others', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/']"
```

(Where `others` is a shorthand for the other key bindings already defined. Just to be sure you don't delete them.)

Now that is out of way, configure your `custom2`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding '<Primary><Alt>s'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ command 'gnome-terminal'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ name 'Open a terminal window'
```